# Take an array and make an object out of flipped indices/values

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a more straightforward way in lodash to achieve the following,

```
var o = _.reduce([2, 3, 7], function(acc, v, i) {
    acc[v] = i || "0";
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Result,

```
Object {2: "0", 3: 1, 7: 2}
```

Comment: Won't you accept pure javascript solution for this?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I will if it is shorter.

Comment: Why are you treating the index 0 as a string but not the other indices?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm using object as lookup hash, and `0` is falsy value unlike `"0"` (which btw can easily be converted back to number if needed). In other words I need `Boolean(o[2])` to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you wanted to use lodash

```
_.fromPairs(_.map(array, (elt, i) => [elt, String(i)]))
```

This works by turning the array into an array of key/value pairs, which you can then use `_.fromPairs` on to turn into an object.

I don't really recommend this, but a one-liner using ES6:

```
Object.assign({}, ...array.map((e, i) => ({[e]: String(i)})))
```

This works by creating a bunch of little one-property objects, then spreading them onto the parameter list of `Object.assign` which will glue them together into one object for you.

Comment: Tnx! Should I worry about performance for arrays under 100 elements?

Comment: @Сухой27 Yes you should. https://jsfiddle.net/h1scorhm/4/ I written a performance test on my own. Check it.

Comment: And I wonder, why OP has accepted this while he is having an efficient pure js solution in other answers

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I don't really care, except that the question was marked lodash and requested a lodash solution. Yes, someone asked if a non-lodash solution was acceptable, and the OP said yes, but the solution you provided was essentially identical to the OP's original solution, merely replacing lodash's `_.reduce` with native reduce (while introducing a gratuitous and confusing use of the comma operator). With regard to performance, if that were the prime concern of either yourself or the OP (who did not even mention it), then you should have proposed a loop instead of `reduce`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy As it is, if I read your benchmark correctly (jsperf is much preferable for such things), the reduce solution is faster than the lodash solution by 5 microseconds per iteration (a difference of 2x). If you are spending your time worrying about such performance differences, good luck holding on to your job, you really must not have very much else on your mind.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `.reduce()` with a starting value of an `empty object`,

```
var obj = [2, 3, 7].reduce(function(a,b,i){
  return (a[b] = i, a);
}, {});
```

If you want it to be shorter even more then use E6 version,

```
var obj = [2, 3, 7].reduce((a,b,i) => (a[b] = i, a), {});
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `return (a.b = i, a);` obfuscation?

Comment: @Сухой27 :  result will be `{b: 2}` ,

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks for pointing that. Was executed just like that in console. But while answering I written it wrongly. :)

Comment: I fail to see why this is better/different than the code the OP already provided, and it doesn't even answer the question, which requested a lodash solution, so it's a bit mysterious why this would be the accepted answer. Nor is it particularly advisable to use the comma operator hack.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy With regard to the obfuscation question from the OP, he did not ask what the result will be, but *is there a reason for it*.

Comment: @Сухой27 That is not an obfuscation. It just used `(exp1,exp2,..n)` methodology. It will be handy in situations where you need to write code concisely.

Answer (score 2):

A pure Javascript solution is

```
var obj = {}
[2, 3, 7].forEach(function(val, i) { obj[val] = i })
```

Obj is then

```
Object {2: 0, 3: 1, 7: 2}
```

Think it's relative simple and has a good readability. It's not completely the same, cause it didn't return the value, but save it in the obj reference.

Comment: So you're essentially building your own little version of reduce by defining your own accumulator variable `obj`. Fail to see why that's an improvement, or why it even qualifies as an answer to a question which requested a lodash solution.